# Trouble decoding .xlsx in Google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, import-from-excel

I can't figure out how to view xlsx data in Google colab. This exact same format has worked for CSV files but it says the codec can't decode certain things. Please help!

```
from google.colab import files

files.download('example_02.xlsx')


from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

Data_03.xlsx(application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet) - 10513 bytes, last modified: 10/3/2019 - 100% done
Saving Data_03.xlsx to Data_03.xlsx

import pandas as pd
import io
mydata_03 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['Data_03.xlsx'].decode('utf-8')))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-cb1bbea653c8> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import io
----> 3 mydata_03 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['Data_03.xlsx'].decode('utf-8')))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

An `xlsx` file isn't a CSV. You'll want to export your spreadsheet as a CSV.

See here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba